# Play 2 Framework dropdown List gives Null Point Exception 

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

am using play 2 framework with java and ebean for data management. I have a problem with my drop down list. the drop down list is populated with data from mySQL database. It was working but looks like I accidentally changed something and now it gives me a null pointer exception when I try to render the page.
I am trying to fix the problem but looks like cannot figure the problem. I provide the codes snippets below.

this is the code that populates the drop down list :

```
public static Result gestureNames()
  {
  List <GestureClassEntity> gcet = GestureClassEntity.find.orderBy("name asc").findList();
  return ok(views.html.train.render(gcet)); 
}
```

this is the route configuration for the method:

```
GET    /name                        controllers.Application.gestureNames()
```

this is the update route file :

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
GET     /socket                     controllers.Application.webSocket()
GET     /cobject                    controllers.Application.classifyObject()
GET    /classify                    controllers.Application.classify()
GET    /name                        controllers.Application.gestureNames()
GET    /train                       controllers.Application.train()
GET    /tclassifier                 controllers.Application.trainClassifier()
```

these are the train and gesturenames methods

```
public static Result train()
  {   
      return ok(train.render(null));
  }

  public static Result gestureNames()
  {
  List <GestureClassEntity> gcet = GestureClassEntity.find.orderBy("name asc").findList();
  return ok(views.html.train.render(gcet)); 
}
```

this is the parameter definition in the scala.html file

```
@( gestureList: List[GestureClassEntity])
```

this is the code for the drop down list:

```
<select class = "selectone">
  @for(gesture <- gestureList){
      <option value = @gesture.id>
        @gesture.getName()
      </option>
  } 
  </select>
```

I get a null point exception when i run the scala.html file.

and this is the stack trace :

```
[error] application -

! @6bjof8n9g - Internal server error, for request [GET /train] ->

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[NullPo
interException: null]]
        at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [
play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
        at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [
play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
        at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.
2]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.
2]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor.j
ar:2.0.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at scala.collection.JavaConversions$JListWrapper.iterator(JavaConversion
s.scala:618) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:73) ~[
scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
        at scala.collection.JavaConversions$JListWrapper.foreach(JavaConversions
.scala:615) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:194)
 ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
        at scala.collection.JavaConversions$JListWrapper.map(JavaConversions.sca
la:615) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
        at views.html.train$.apply(train.template.scala:50) ~[classes/:na]
```

can anyone help me with this problem cos I have to submit the project as an assignment and I am late.

thank you all.

Comment: Looks like you have a null `GestureClassEntity` in your list.

Comment: It looks like that , but when I use the system.out.println I am able iterate and print the objects. So kind of thinking may be there is something am missing in the route file or when defining the parameter in the scala.html.file template

Comment: Or it seems that this is the List which is null in your template.

Comment: it is likely that the list in the template is null as you suggested but how can I check that the list is null or not null. Because it means that may be the problem is with Template List or the route file GET method. I am confuse here.

Comment: Did you try to load `http://localhost:9000/name` URL in your browser ? Because, the error appears when you hit `/train`, but you did not show the mapping of the `/train` URL in your routes file.

Comment: Wow , I just tried what u suggested and the the page was successfully rendered. It got me excited. Thanks a lot. Guess i now have to figure out what the problem is. Do u have any suggestions

Comment: Please show the full routes file (in particular the /train Url mapping)

Comment: I have added the full list of GET methods in the route file. Please note that route has thesame arrangements of methods as I have presented them here.

Comment: And show the `controllers.Application.train()` method

Comment: I have added the train and the gestureNames methods. They are just below the GET methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the call of the `/train` Url, because it is mapped to the `train()` method which call the template with a list of `GestureClassEntity` which is null:

```
GET    /train                       controllers.Application.train()
```

then it calls:

```
public static Result train()
  {   
      return ok(train.render(null)); // <- here is the problem
  }
```

Comment: SO what you are saying is that the train method should rather return the gcet object and not a null object.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and it worked. thanks a thousand times